# dirtychange is not called on selecting a value in combo in extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have created a panel and stored combobox and radio group in it like below

```
Ext.define('EMS.config.view.Config', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

items: createAlertUserDropdown(),
       createRadioGroup()

createAlertUserDropdown: function() {
    this.comboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        emptyText: RP.getMessage('ems.common.selectuser'),
        itemId: 'ooofalertdropdown',
        allowBlank: false,
        store: this.configUserDropdownStore,
        queryMode: 'local',
        valueField: 'userId',
        displayField: 'userDisplay',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        width:276,
        margin:'-5 0 0 0',
        typeAhead: true,
        scope: this
    });

    createRadioGroup: function() {--------------}
```

I have created a new class which extends above class and given an ID (id: 'configConfigConfigView',)

```
Ext.define('EMS.tf.config.config.view.Config', {
extend: 'EMS.config.view.Config',
alias: 'widget.ems-config-config-config',

/**
 * We set an id because we want this to be a singleton.
 */
id: 'configConfigConfigView',
```

And now in my controller class I have defined references like this:

```
me.control({
        '#configConfigConfigView button[action=save]': {
            click: me.onSave, autoQualify: false
        },
        '#configConfigConfigView button[action=cancel]': {
            click: me.onCancel, autoQualify: false
        },
        '#configConfigConfigView rpToggle[itemId=oooftoggle]': {
            change: me.onToggle, autoQualify: false
        },
        '#configConfigConfigView radio': {
            change: me.onRadioGroupToggle, autoQualify: false
        },
        '#configConfigConfigView': {
            activate: me.onConfigRender,
            dirtychange: me.onDirty,
            autoQualify: false
        }
    });
```

The problem is when I select a any of the radio button in the group it is calling me.onDirty() function but not when selecting a value from the dropdown which means dirtychange is not firing on selecting a different value in the combo.

Surprisingly the function get called when selecting value in the drop down after three iterations. I am not sure what is the reason. Please help me.

Comment: Why did you choose to listen to `'changedirty'` event instead of  `'change'`?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. If I put an additional textbox to the form and start typing in it will call me.onDirty() function but only combo is not calling on change.

Comment: Try listening for combobox's select event